# Use event @change and @click to get data pull-and-drop in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop

**Template:**

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 mt-2">
            <draggable
             class="list-group"
             tag="ul"
             v-model="imgList.top"
             v-bind="dragOptions"
             >
                                  
             <transition-group type="transition">
               <li
               class="list-group-item" style="align-items: center;display: flex;padding: 12px 15px; font-size: 13px"
                  v-for="record in imgList.top"
                  :key="record._id"
                  @click="onClickValue"
                  <!-- @change="onChangeValue" -->
                >
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <img class="w-100" :src="getImageURL(record.image)" alt />
            </div>
            </li>
            </transition-group>
        </draggable>
       </div>
    </div>



<script>
    import draggable from "vuedraggable";
    export default {
      components: {
          draggable
       },
      data() {
        return {
          imgList: {
             top: [
               {_id: '12354356444433', image: '09jgg24.jpg'},
               {_id: '12354356442211', image: '09jaef2.jpg'},
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
         onClickValue() {
           console.log('ok') // No results received
        },
        //onChangeValue() {
        //   console.log('ok') // No results received
        //},
      }
    }
</script>
```

I am doing `drag-and-drop` in vuejs. I hold the image and drag and drop it.. Now I want when I drag an image to catch the `@click` or `@change` event. I tried putting @click and `@change` in my code. But when I drag and drop nothing appears? Please show me to catch that event. Thank you

Comment: See if this helps -> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: thank @Amaarrockz. But I do it that way. if I reload the page, haven't dragged the image yet it appears the value

Comment: That might be a different issue which could be handled